# MySql Workbench Target host is configured as Windows, but seems to be a different OS. Please review the connection settings

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

hoy tras instalar por segunda vez MySQL en windows desde este [enlace](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html?fbclid=IwAR2oq1r3XlFGzYZ3xv4qHpS0zqIMnCqlRG0OwSUb5UmROGKVjrd0-BdPKtY), tras instalarlo en modo desarrollo, abrí mysql workbench para poder ver mi "server status" y me salio este error

[image: Error]

Mi system profile es el siguiente

[image: System profile]

Que puede ser? que hago?

Comment: Sebastián: si tienes una respuesta diferente a la mía, no edites mi respuesta, escribe una respuesta nueva y explicas por qué afirmas que esa es la respuesta. Te voy a seguir rechazando las ediciones a mi respuesta. No tengo evidencia para afirmar algo diferente, de pronto tú sí.

Comment: @Alfabravo mis disculpas, era yo quién estaba editando tú respuesta.

Comment: Soy nuevo en stackoverflow y nosé editar nada u.u

Comment: @SebastiánGarcíaMuñoz algo que si podés hacer, es marcar como "aceptada" la respuesta de Alfabravo, dale click al check que aparece debajo de la puntuación de la pregunta del compañero, así tu pregunta aparecerá como resuelta (Si fue que la espuesta de Alfabravo te funcionó claro)

Answer (score 2):

Me pasaba lo mismo, la solución al parecer es activar una opción en la configuracion regional de windows, el proceso a seguir es el siguiente:

1. Entras en la configuración de país o región de windows:

[image: configuracion de cambiar pais o region de windows]

2. Una vez ahi, abajo del todo hay una opción que te lleva a configuraciones relacionadas:

[image: Una vez ahi, abajo del todo hay una opción que te lleva a configuraciones relacionadas]

3. ahi le das a región:

[image: ahi le das a región]

4. Se te abrirá una ventana nueva, tienes que darle a "Cambiar configuración regional del sistema" en la pestaña de Administración:

[image: Configuración regional del sistema]

5. Por ultimo en la ventana que se te abrirá tienes que marcar el checkbox que pone beta de usar UTF-8 para compatibilidad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de esto te pide reiniciar el pc y en principio después debería de funcionar.

Parece que si no esta marcada esa opción, con esta versión de MySQL y con windows 10 no funciona.

También, comprueba que el servicio "MySQL80" esté puesto como arranque manual y no automático o desactivado, esto se puede hacer desde el administrador de tareas>servicios>click derecho>Abrir Servicios y una vez ahi buscar el servicio y click derecho>propiedades>Tipo de inicio.

Si después de reiniciar el pc te da problemas al conectar desde el Workbench a la BD , cierra el workbench y la BD, detén el servicio MySQL80 desde el administrador de tareas y vuelve a abrir la BD desde el ejecutable.

Answer (score 1):

Tiene toda la pinta de ser un [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102310) en la versión de MySQL. No podemos afirmar que sea en Workbench o no; simplemente es un posible bug en el instalador completo de MySQL para Windows que incluye el Workbench (para quien quiso editar la respuesta)

Prueba con la versión inmediatamente anterior, 8.0.22, que está en los [archivos](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/installer/).