# Error Mysql: ''RuntimeError: Target host is configured as windows, but seems to be a different OS. ."

Tags: mysql-workbench

estoy iniciando en esto de base de datos con Mysql y necesito un poco de ayuda.

Estoy trabajando en windows 10, con mysqlworkbench, se supone que todo está actualizado en su ultima versión.

Tenía el programa instalado desde hace un tiempo y funcionaba todo bien, quería actualizar los conectores pero mejor actualicé todo el paquete con el installer, pero después de eso no me quiere correr la base de datos que tenía, ya probé desinstalando el programa completamente y no quiere, cuando trato de iniciar la base de datos me muestra el siguiente error:

"Could not acquire management access for administration ''RuntimeError: Target host is configured as windows, but seems to be a different OS. Please review the connection settings."

despues de varios intentos sin saber que hacer el programa se cierra solo.

Como detalle importante y no sé si tendrá algo que ver pero antes de actualizar Mysql actualicé el windows 10, ignoro si esto afecta en algo.

Adjunto imagen del mensaje mostrado y de la configuración guardada que es la que da error.

He tratado de buscar lo que hay respecto al tema pero no he tenido suerte. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Saludos.

[image: Configuración guardada]

[image: Error MySqlWorkbench]

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/424325/29967). Parece ser un BUG.

Comment: Instale la versión del MySQL WorkBench 8.0.22, eso solucionará el problema.

Comment: Mira esto, seguro que te ayuda si aún te hace falta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server Un saludo