# ¿Porqué recibo el error MySql Workbench Target host is configured as Windows, but seems to be a different OS si el "Target" está bien configurado?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Tras actualizar MySQL Workbench a la versión 8.0.23 en *Windows 10* he tenido problemas al tratar de abrir el "Options file" en el panel "Adminitration" de mi instancia, muestra el mensaje de error:

> MySql Workbench Target host is configured as Windows, but seems to be a different OS. Please review the connection settings

Y no puedo abrir el archivo de opciones.

¿Alguien ha logrado resolverlo?

Ya he revisado cambiar el entorno del sistema operativo, pero está bien configurado: Windows para MySQL 5.7

[image: Configuracion del perfil de la instancia]

**Actualización:**

El problema afecta también la opción "Table Data Export".

Resulta que con la versión 8.0.23 tampoco podía usar la opción de exportar datos de una tabla mediante el "wizard" sin ningún mensaje de error, Workbench únicamente se cerraba (crasheaba). Desconozco si solo en mi caso el problema era así de agravado.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424325/mysql-workbench-target-host-is-configured-as-windows-but-seems-to-be-a-differen)

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias, tu solución me funcionó de maravila.

Comment: Lo curioso es que en la pregunta original, no me aceptaron la respuesta aún (T_T)  Pero me alegra que te sirviera :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Bueno, al menos por acá tú respuesta queda registrada y enlazada a la pregunta original, quizás así sea aceptada en un futuro cercano :-D

Comment: Confirmo colega, la solucion fue desintalar en mi caso el Workbench 8.0.25 e instalar el 8.0.22 y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logré resolver el asunto** poco después de elaborar la pregunta. Resulta ser que, según el usuario [alfabravo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6798/alfabravo) **es un bug del workbench** como tal.

**La solución fue reinstalar la versión anterior inmediata de MySQL Workbench** (Yo instalé la 8.0.23 por lo que volví a 8.0.22) y así el problema fue resuelto para mi caso.

Dejo esta respuesta por si fuera de utilidad par alguien más...

Fuente interna de stack overflow: [MySql Workbench Target host is configured as Windows, but seems to be a different OS. Please review the connection settings](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424325/mysql-workbench-target-host-is-configured-as-windows-but-seems-to-be-a-differen)

Comment: Confirmo, me sirvió volver a la versión anterior. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema se puede solucionar para cualquier versión del Workbench (estoy usando la 8.0.27) cambiando una configuración de idioma:

- Panel de control >
- Región >
- Pestaña Administrativo >
- Cambiar configuración regional del sistema
- Marcar "Versión beta: Use UTF-8 Unicode para la compatibilidad de idioma en todo el mundo"
- Reiniciar Windows

La respuesta original está [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70034301/3762771)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando me sale ese error, en mi caso, es porque el servicio MySQL80 lo tengo detenido ó deshabilitado. Voy a Service, busco MySQL80, lo habilito y lo pongo en ejecución. Vuelve a funcionar correctamente con todas las bases y tablas que tenía.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

La manera de solucionar este problema radica en el sistema de codificación empleado por una función incluida en un script de python usado por MySQL para obtener los datos del sistema:

•   Editar el archivo 'os_utils.py' en la ruta:

'C:\Archivos de programa\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench'

•   Buscar la siguiente línea:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

•   Modificar el parámetro encoding='utf-8' a encoding='ansi' de manera que quede:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding='ansi', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me saltó el mismo error a partir de que modifiqué los puertos en el archivo de  ***my.ini*** en  el Xampp.

Lo solucioné modificando en Connection (Workbench), por el puerto mas reciente (el modificado). [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]